# On Error GoTo <label> not working

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a simple command button on a form, the "click" event procedure is used to import an Excel file into the database line by line as part of a customised process.  I've set my:

```
On Error GoTo DtUplErr
```

At the beginning of the procedure, and have also checked the VBA options to ensure "Break on unhandled error's is my option", however it simply will not move to my Handle bookmark and instead throws the standard runtime error prompt.

The actual procedure itself makes use of a workspace to carry out the updates (not sure if this should cause an issue)

The error I'm breaking on is 3022 (Duplicate Values) which I do intend to see and also capture so it's not a bad data issue.

I've tried importing all my objects into a clean mdb and still no luck, I'm really confused.

Any suggestions?

Full code (Apologies for amount)

```
Private Sub cmdSelect_Click()

'MS Excel
Dim xlApp       As Object 'Late Binding
Dim xlWrkBk     As Object
Dim xlWrkSt     As Object
Dim lngRow      As Long
Dim lngRowCnt   As Long

'Recordsets/Workspace
Dim WkSp        As DAO.Workspace 'Transaction Buffer
Dim rsMs        As DAO.Recordset 'Master
Dim rsSu        As DAO.Recordset 'Supplier
Dim rsAd        As DAO.Recordset 'Address
Dim rsAs        As DAO.Recordset 'Asset

'Misc
Dim strFile     As String
Dim dblMPRN     As Double
Dim lngPerc     As Long

On Error GoTo DtUplErr

Loading 1
strFile = DataUploadDialog
If strFile & "" = "" Then Exit Sub 'Quit if no file selected

'Open up the file
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWrkBk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
Set xlWrkSt = xlWrkBk.Worksheets(1)

Forms!frmUpload!cmdHidden.SetFocus
DoCmd.Hourglass -1

'Validate file format before import
With xlWrkSt
    If .Range("A1") <> "MPRN" _
    Or .Range("B1") <> "Notification" _
    Or .Range("C1") <> "Asset" _
    Or .Range("D1") <> "Reference No." _
    Or .Range("E1") <> "WMS Job No." _
    Or .Range("F1") <> "Meter Worker" _
    Or .Range("G1") <> "Job Status" _
    Or .Range("H1") <> "Date" _
    Or .Range("I1") <> "Time" _
    Or .Range("J1") <> "Sales district" _
    Or .Range("K1") <> "Customer" _
    Or .Range("L1") <> "Location" _
    Or .Range("M1") <> "Additional Info" _
    Or .Range("N1") <> "Street" _
    Or .Range("O1") <> "Dependent Locality" _
    Or .Range("P1") <> "Post Town" _
    Or .Range("Q1") <> "Postal Code" _
    Or .Range("R1") <> "Serial number" _
    Or .Range("S1") <> "Cur. Serial No." _
    Or .Range("T1") <> "Manufacturer Code" _
    Or .Range("U1") <> "Model Code" _
    Or .Range("V1") <> "Year of Manufacture" _
    Then
        xlWrkBk.Close
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWrkBk = Nothing
        Set xlWrkSt = Nothing

        DoCmd.Hourglass 0

        MsgBox "Selected file is not in the correct format, please ensure " & _
               "the original column headers have not been moved/renamed" & _
               vbCr & vbCr & _
               "For further assistance please contact app support", 48
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

Forms!frmUpload!cmdSelect.Enabled = 0
Forms!frmUpload!cmdClose.Enabled = 0

'Get total number of rows in file
lngRow = 1

Do Until xlWrkSt.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value & "" = ""
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop

lngRowCnt = lngRow - 2

'Start writing to the tables
Set WkSp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

WkSp.BeginTrans

    Set rsMs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblMaster", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set rsSu = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSupplierHist", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set rsAd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblAddress", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set rsAs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblAssetHist", dbOpenDynaset)

    lngRow = 2

    Do Until lngRow > lngRowCnt + 1

ProcessUpload:
        With xlWrkSt

            dblMPRN = .Range("A" & lngRow) 'Store MPRN for additional tables

            'Master
            rsMs.AddNew
                rsMs!MPRN = dblMPRN
                rsMs!LoadTimestamp = Now()
                rsMs!Notification = .Range("B" & lngRow)
                rsMs!Asset = .Range("C" & lngRow)
                rsMs!JobRef = .Range("D" & lngRow)
                rsMs!WmsJobRef = .Range("E" & lngRow)
                rsMs!MeterWorker = .Range("F" & lngRow)
                rsMs!JobStatus = .Range("G" & lngRow)
                rsMs!JobTimestamp = .Range("H" & lngRow) & " " & .Range("I" & lngRow)
                rsMs!SalesDistrict = .Range("J" & lngRow)
                rsMs!AddInfo = .Range("M" & lngRow)
            rsMs.Update

            'Supplier
            rsSu.AddNew
                rsSu!MPRN = dblMPRN
                rsSu!SupplierID = .Range("K" & lngRow)
                rsSu!Timestamp = Now()
                rsSu!Advisor = "System"
            rsSu.Update

            'Address
            rsAd.AddNew
                rsAd!MPRN = dblMPRN
                rsAd!Street = .Range("N" & lngRow)
                rsAd!Locality = .Range("O" & lngRow)
                rsAd!Town = .Range("P" & lngRow)
                rsAd!PostCode = .Range("Q" & lngRow)
            rsAd.Update

            'Asset
            rsAs.AddNew
                rsAs!MPRN = dblMPRN
                rsAs!SN = .Range("R" & lngRow)
                rsAs!Make = .Range("T" & lngRow)
                rsAs!Model = .Range("U" & lngRow)
                rsAs!YOM = .Range("V" & lngRow)
                rsAs!Location = .Range("L" & lngRow)
                rsAs!Timestamp = Now()
                rsAs!Advisor = "System"
            rsAs.Update

            'Work out progress
            lngPerc = Round((lngRow / lngRowCnt) * 100)
            lngPerc = IIf(lngPerc > 0, lngPerc - 1, lngPerc)

            Forms!frmUpload!txtPerc = lngPerc & "/" & lngRowCnt & "  (" & lngPerc & " %)"
            Forms!frmUpload!ProgBar.Value = lngPerc

            'Let the display catch up
            DoEvents
            Sleep 100

            lngRow = lngRow + 1 'Advance

        End With

    Loop

WkSp.CommitTrans

Forms!frmUpload!txtPerc = lngRowCnt & "/" & lngRowCnt & "  (100 %)"
Forms!frmUpload!ProgBar.Value = 100
DoEvents

'Cleanup
xlWrkBk.Close
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWrkBk = Nothing
Set xlWrkSt = Nothing

rsMs.Close
rsSu.Close
rsAd.Close
rsAs.Close
WkSp.Close
Set rsMs = Nothing
Set rsSu = Nothing
Set rsAd = Nothing
Set rsAs = Nothing
Set WkSp = Nothing

Forms!frmUpload!cmdClose.Enabled = -1

DoCmd.Hourglass 0

Exit Sub

DtUplErr:
Select Case Err

    Case 3022 'Index Violation (Assumed PK MPRN in tblMaster)
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        GoTo ProcessUpload

    Case Else 'Cleanup and then show error
        WkSp.Rollback 'Cancel transaction so data not affected

        xlWrkBk.Close
        xlApp.Quit
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWrkBk = Nothing
        Set xlWrkSt = Nothing

        rsMs.Close
        rsSu.Close
        rsAd.Close
        rsAs.Close
        WkSp.Close
        Set rsMs = Nothing
        Set rsSu = Nothing
        Set rsAd = Nothing
        Set rsAs = Nothing
        Set WkSp = Nothing

        Forms!frmUpload!cmdSelect.Enabled = -1
        Forms!frmUpload!cmdClose.Enabled = -1

        DoCmd.Hourglass 0

        ShowError Err, "ModFunctions", "DataUpload", Err.Description

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What does the rest of the code look like?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Please see update, apologies it's a large procedure and I don't have time to strip it down.

Comment: This goes to the error coding after it has been compiled when I try it. Has you compacted and repaired? Decompiled?

Comment: @Remou Yep, forgot to mention, it still does it after a compact repair. How do I decompile?

Comment: @Remou No worries, found the decompile, still no change unfortunately.

Comment: Since there was no change after decompile, can you duplicate the problem with a stripped down version of your procedure?

Comment: @HansUp A very simple version of the procedure seems to work (very strange) I will go through it methodically and hopefully work out the rogue coding, if so then I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @HansUp, I stepped through my code trying to stop the root of the error and as I expected it's the simplest (yet most infrutiating) of things.

On the first error my code would as intended run to this point:

```
DtUplErr:
    Select Case Err

    Case 3022 'Index Violation (Assumed PK MPRN in tblMaster)
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        GoTo ProcessUpload
```

Then back we go to the next item and the rest of the process, however on the next error it would fail, and it's all down to one "word" effectively, I've changed the line:

```
Goto ProcessUpload
```

To:

```
Resume ProcessUpload
```

Now the error's are continued to be handled, phew, I always knew there was a good reason for the "Resume" keyword over "GoTo" but until now have not felt the misery of getting it wrong ^_^

Comment: Congrats.  It was unrealistic to expect us to debug that monolithic procedure ... right at the start we have no idea what `Loading 1` does, and it only got worse from there.  I really think for your own benefit you should "modularize" that procedure more.  For starters, move the "Validate file format before import" section into a separate function.  And so forth.

Comment: @HansUp Cheers for the advice, the code was written as makes most sense to my project, the validate file is a one off and only related to this procedure so no need for the separation in this instance, I appreciate some of the other references namely "Loading" and "DataUploadDialog" don't make sense as your right they relate to other functions. It's why I was reluctant to upload the code at first as I knew 99.9% was fine but I just couldn't find that one bit.

Comment: But modularizing the code makes it easier to throw away the parts (like showing update progress) which don't affect the problem you're asking us to debug.  And then no need to apologize for giving us such a large procedure to examine.  :-)  But really the quickest route to joy was the one you got round to eventually ... run the code in break (debug) mode, step through the procedure line by line, and see which triggers the error.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of simplifying your code to make future trouble shooting easier, I offer this suggestion.

Change the section from `'Cleanup` to `Exit Sub` to this:

```
MySubShallHaveOnlyOneExitPoint:
    xlWrkBk.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWrkBk = Nothing
    Set xlWrkSt = Nothing
    rsMs.Close
    rsSu.Close
    rsAd.Close
    rsAs.Close
    WkSp.Close
    Set rsMs = Nothing
    Set rsSu = Nothing
    Set rsAd = Nothing
    Set rsAs = Nothing
    Set WkSp = Nothing
    Forms!frmUpload!cmdClose.Enabled = -1
    DoCmd.Hourglass 0
    Exit Sub
```

Then the `Case Else` in your error handler can be simplified to this:

```
Case Else ' Cleanup and then show error '
    WkSp.Rollback ' Cancel transaction so data not affected '
    Forms!frmUpload!cmdSelect.Enabled = -1
    ShowError Err, "ModFunctions", "DataUpload", Err.Description
    Resume MySubShallHaveOnlyOneExitPoint
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, I like saving repeat code whenever possible, sometimes hard to see the wood for the tree's, especially when more is added in to the original procedure afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  'Number' Property Returned by Default of Err Object.

<strike>I think the problem lies in your `Select Case` statement.  Your missing the 'Number' property of the err object. So It's just skipping the entire `Select Case` block</strike>

```
DtUplErr:
Select Case Err.Number 'Use the Error Number for your Select Case Statement

    Case 3022 'Index Violation (Assumed PK MPRN in tblMaster)
        lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Err.Clear
        On Error Goto DtUplErr 'might need to tell it to branch on error again, i havn't tested
        GoTo ProcessUpload

    Case Else 'Cleanup and then show error
        MsgBox Err.Description
        'do whatever here
End Select
```

Comment: The Err property returns the number by default and as such does not need this extension. Although the main problem is that my code doesn't even reach this point.